# Error when trying to set a value to 0

Tags: solidity, ethjs

I have a mapping that maps addresses to uints:

```
mapping (address => uint256) mapAddress;
```

A function then assigns a counter to the address:

```
mapAddress[msg.sender] ++;
```

This gives me `1.`

The problem is that I'm getting an error when trying to set the counter back to 0:

```
function resetCounter() public payable returns(bool) {
    if (mapAddress[msg.sender] > 0) {
        mapAddress[msg.sender] = 0;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

the function above gives me this error:

```
transact to Contract.resetCounter errored: Error: Error: [ethjs-query] while 
formatting outputs from RPC 'undefined' for method 'sendRawTransaction' 
Error: [ethjs-format] hex string 'undefined' must be an alphanumeric 66 utf8 
byte hex (chars: a-fA-F) string, is 0 bytes
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: What is the development environment? It can appear a problem related to RPC interface, not to the code shown, that is correct but for the “payable” attribution to the resetCounter, apparently not justified.

Comment: I am using Remix IDE with Ganache (injected Web3).

Comment: Try the same in JavaScript VM

Comment: It worked in JavaScript VM. I have also removed the "payable" attribute. How to make it work with Injected Web3? I am confused.

Comment: The problem is on your RPC. If you are using ganache, may be that without the “payable” it works now (there is a bug about that at the moment).

Comment: Oh yes, I’ve seen just now you said you are using ganache... try now then

Comment: Will this problem occur also on mainnet?

Comment: Not at all. It is a problem related to ganache core only.

Comment: I deleted payable, but the problem is still there. I will try to test my contract with Javascript VM and on Ropsten to see if it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you hit a known bug of the current versions of ganache (at least from 1.21 they all suffer this).

According to ganache developers it is related to the gas estimation phase, to be fixed, popping up for payable attribution (functions for sure and may be addresses)

If your code works on JavaScript VM, it shall works on testnets and on mainnet without problems at all.